# java open csv file using excel

Tags: java

I am making a project for college and have made a program which creates csv files. I would like there to be a button which you can click which then opens the csv file with excel. Thanks

Comment: I'm afraid you forgot the question.

Comment: Did you mean when you click a button made in java program, you should end up opening that .csv file ?

Comment: If you're interested in using a library, Open CSV has come a long way: https://www.baeldung.com/opencsv

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Knowing that MsOffice is installed on the system, you should be able to open a document with it from command line using the command

```
excel myDoc.csv
```

to execute such a command from java, you could use this snapshot:

```
File myCSVFile; //reference to your file here 
String execString = "excel " + myCSVFile.getAbsolutePath();
Runtime run = Runtime.getRuntime();
try {
    Process pp = run.exec(execString);
} catch(Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

This is somewhat rough and needs styling, of course, but generally it should work. Besides, to be more graceful you could also check Windows registry, using the [java.util.prefs.Preferences](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/prefs/Preferences.html) class, to know if MsOffice is installed and, if yes, where. But, please, be aware, if you are reckoning for MsExcel (as I understood from your post), this will automatically cancel Java's multiplatform approach. Hopefully, this helps :)

Answer (score 3):

If you are using Java 6 you can use the [Desktop](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/Desktop.html) class. Read also [Opening, Editing, and Printing a File](http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/J2SE/Desktop/javase6/desktop_api/)

Comment: A good point! But note, that Desktop.open(File file) method opens the file with a system default program, not with a specific one (like Excel in this case). It may well be that CSV would be set to be opened with another program, like Notepad++ or whatever.

Comment: @Coryffaeus you are right. But IMHO it should be the user's choice what program opens csv-files. And the `Desktop` solution also handles the case when no Excel is installed.

Answer (score 0):

You can use JExcel API. It will be very easy for you.

Answer (score 0):

For whatever reason, **execString**'s provided did not work for me, but the one below worked:

```
String execString = "cmd /c start excel \"" + filePathString + "\"";
```

With the other **exeString**'s I kept getting an exception saying that the runtime cannot find the file - **start** or **excel**.